# Multiple Contextual filters, taxonomy and date, on one content type

Tags: datetime, views

I have an event content type. I want two jump menus on the primary view page: one to filter by date (month) and one to filter by taxonomy (category).

I have used views with contextual filters to build the page and jump menus (as attachments). If I only use one filter/jump menu attachment on the view, either one works perfectly. If I put both attachments on the view page, there is some sort of conflict and they stop working.

Is it possible to have two contextual filters on one view page? If so, what do I need to do to make the work together?